# Why did the Riverworld Ethicals give Richard Francis Burton some important advice that they didn't expect him to remember?

Tags: philip-jose-farmer, riverworld

This is a question that has nagged at me since right after I first read [***To Your Scattered Bodies Go,***](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?730781) the first volume of Philip José Farmer's ambitious Riverworld series. But I've never raised the subject online before.

Farmer wrote four more full-length books set on the Riverworld. (*The Fabulous Riverboat, The Dark Design, The Magic Labyrinth,* and *Gods of Riverworld*.) I ended up buying and reading them all. None of those later volumes provided any clear-cut answer for this question (contrary to my expectations at the time). However, I've recently learned via Wikipedia that there were some later Riverworld anthologies which I've never read (done on the "shared universe" model, with many authors, including Farmer himself, contributing new material), so something in one of those books may have squarely addressed this point. And, of course, there's always the possibility that Farmer may have said something about this in some other setting, outside of his published fiction -- during a convention appearance, for instance. Something which I've never seen, but which some alert fellow fan might be able to call to my attention.

For my question to make sense to anyone reading this who doesn't instantly remember every little detail of the first Riverworld novel, I need to summarize the key events from the novel which created the situation that bothered me so much.

**The Set-Up:**

1. The novel's protagonist is Farmer's interpretation of a real-life historical figure, Sir Richard Francis Burton, a British explorer, linguist, military officer, author, etc., who traveled to many parts of the globe and did many fascinating things in the Nineteenth Century. He died in Trieste in 1890. In Farmer's version, of course, Burton then woke up again, "immediately" from his point of view (but actually thousands of years later), on the Riverworld, in a healthy body that appeared to be a cloned copy of what Burton had originally looked like when he was about twenty-five years old.
2. In Chapter 29, the next-to-last chapter of *To Your Scattered Bodies Go,* Burton wakes up in a conference room. Twelve other human beings are present (six men and six women). It is implied, but not stated for a fact (not in this volume, at least) that these twelve are the *highest-ranking* members of the Ethical administration; a sort of governing Council.
3. The members of this modestly self-labelled "Ethical" culture are human beings, living thousands of years after our era, and claiming to be much more advanced in ethical terms. Before this novel got going, the members of their culture had labored long and hard to carefully reshape the surface of an Earthlike planet to give it a single River, over ten million miles long, plus various other embellishments tailored to suit their own mysterious purposes. When all was in readiness, the Ethicals then resurrected, *all at once,* roughly thirty-six billion human beings who had lived and died in previous eras of human history (up through the year 2008, according to what we were told in this first book). When these newly-resurrected people awoke in the strange environment of the Rivervalley, they were basically left to fend for themselves. The Ethicals did all this *without* bothering to give any helpful orientation lectures on just what the new "rules of the game" were supposed to be, and why! (Which, of course, sets up the major mysteries of the series for Burton and other resurrected characters to try to solve.)
4. Loga, one of the twelve people on this council, does most of the talking to Burton in this scene. After briefly alluding to some sort of giant living computer which has warned the Ethicals about certain men who might become serious threads to the official Ethical agenda, Loga says cautiously: "That’s all I care to tell you -- even though you won’t remember a thing that occurs down here after we send you back to the Rivervalley." Plain implication: They're going to do a careful editing job on Burton's memories before they turn him loose in the general population again. They don't want him to remember any details that might be mentioned "here and now."
5. But later in this chapter, as the conversation is wrapping up, Loga also tells Burton that he *must stop* his current method of hopping around the Riverworld via self-inflicted death followed by thoroughly-automated resurrection that always leaves him waking up somewhere far away in a perfectly healthy body. (This is a travel method which Burton has previously called "the Suicide Express." He has used it -- not always dying by choice -- **777** times before this scene.)

I'll quote the key passage:

> "There’s a Judas among you," Burton said, enjoying the effect of his
> words.
>
> But the jewel-eyed man said, "Why don’t you tell him the truth, Loga?
> It’ll wipe off that sickening smirk and put him in his proper place."
>
> Loga hesitated, then said, "Very well, Thanabur. Burton, you will have
> to be very careful from now on. You must not commit suicide and you
> must fight as hard to stay alive as you did on Earth, when you thought
> you had only one life. There is a limit to the number of times a man
> may be resurrected. After a certain amount -- it varies and there’s no
> way to predict the individual allotment -- the psychomorph seems
> unable to reattach itself to the body. Every death weakens the
> attraction between body and psychomorph. Eventually, the psychomorph
> comes to the point of no return. It becomes a -- well, to use an
> unscientific term -- a 'lost soul.' It wanders bodiless through the
> universe; we can detect these unattached psychomorphs without
> instruments, unlike those of the -- how shall I put it? -- the
> 'saved,' which disappear entirely from our ken.
>
> "So you see, you must give up this form of travel by death. This is
> why continued suicide by those poor unfortunates who cannot face life
> is, if not the unforgivable sin, the irrevocable."

6. Thanabur, the jewel-eyed man, then speaks up, confirming what Loga has just said.
7. A few moments later, Burton is suddenly rendered unconscious . . . and in Chapter 30, he wakes up in a part of the Riverworld where the local residents include some of his dear friends (from earlier chapters of the book which described his first few years on the Riverworld). There is a possible implication that the Ethicals deliberately placed him right there, among friends, as a sort of bribe to try to persuade Burton to settle down in one spot on the Riverworld for a while. But Burton quickly makes it clear that he still intends to keep trying to reach the end of the River (and thus the "Dark Tower" which is believed to be the Ethical Headquarters on this planet).
8. Burton is also elated to realize he still remembers, vividly, the meeting I just described -- the one he'd been told he'd forget! His quick conclusion is that a renegade Ethical, whom he had met once before (without seeing the face or hearing the natural voice), and whom he thinks of as "the Mysterious Stranger," must have found a way to secretly sabotage the process that was supposed to erase certain things from Burton's memory. Burton concludes that this means the Mysterious Stranger is not just any old rank-and-file Ethical, but presumably one of those twelve leaders whom he recently met.

**My Thoughts When I First Read Book 1**

1. After I first read *To Your Scattered Bodies Go,* I filled up a few pages with notes about the various questions and theories that were racing through my head regarding where Farmer might be going with this series. While doing so, I realized it was very peculiar that Loga, in Chapter 29, tells Burton he won't remember this chat after it's over . . . and then, later in that same scene, Loga *stresses* the point that Burton must immediately stop committing suicide, because his next death could turn out to be the one that was incurable!
2. Furthermore, I took note that Thanabur was the one who had first prompted Loga to make that very point to Burton, and he also took the trouble to confirm the accuracy of Loga's detailed explanation of why endless suicide was such a bad idea in the long run.
3. Even if we granted for the sake of argument that either Loga or Thanabur might have been the person who made sure Burton's memory of this scene would remain, and thus had an ulterior motive for seizing the opportunity to tip him off about the dangers of the Suicide Express --

> -- And the idea that at least one of those two men was secretly a renegade was *confirmed* in a later volume of the series --

-- wouldn't the other eleven "sincere Ethicals," the ones dedicated to upholding the Sacred Status Quo in accordance with the official agenda, have been smart enough to observe that there was something awfully peculiar about their colleagues going to all that trouble to tell Burton, in detail, something that he supposedly wasn't going to remember long enough for it to make any difference? (I assumed that people who are not geniuses will never make it to this governing council in the first place, so it shouldn't be all that easy to get them to overlook the inconsistencies when you behave "illogically," right in front of them.)

4. Shortly after I first read this volume (many and many a year ago), I reached the tentative conclusion that the whole scene was a carefully staged performance, meaning that *all twelve* members of this guiding council were fully on board with some Machiavellian plan that *required* Burton remembering everything so that his future behavior would be modified by this newfound knowledge. But, for some reason, they wanted him to *think* it was only by a lucky fluke (probably "clandestine interference by a secret rebel") that he could remember the whole thing.

**The Expanded Version of the Question**

So, to rephrase and expand the question from my title for this post: Does anyone know if Farmer, or any of the other SF writers who were invited to participate by contributing "canonical" material to the Riverworld universe in later years, ever offered *any explanation* of why Burton was given such important advice in Chapter 29, which -- if we took things at face value -- at least 11 of those 12 members of the Council should have assumed he *wasn't* going to remember for long enough to do him any good, and thus there was absolutely no point in offering the advice in the first place?

Comment: You're probably overthinking it. Farmer may not have thought it through as carefully as you have!

Comment: I love Farmer and the first two books of this series. I assumed there was more to the undercover ethical than the other ethicals understood, and the elder was having moral conflicts which caused him to go through the motions of censoring Burton without following through.

Comment: @Jim Conant -- there were things I didn't bother mentioning about my own thought processes when I was preparing the question a few days ago. One was that when I first read the series, long ago, it became *painfully obvious* that during the gap between Books 2 and 3, PJF *drastically* changed course regarding his premises and intentions for the whole thing. Several "facts" from the first two books were shamelessly contradicted by new statements and "discoveries" in #3. But perhaps the "original plan," whatever it was, would have addressed the problem that nagged at me right after I read Book 1?

Comment: @Major Stackings -- Now that you mention it, I admit it is quite possible that the renegade allowed Burton to keep those memories, not because there were any *vitally useful* clues contained within that conversation which Burton might need in his future endeavors, but merely because he found it *morally repugnant* to wipe out some of a man's memories as a matter of convenience. But that still leaves the question of why all the other members of the Council would fail to *notice* that Burton was being given "useful advice" which he wasn't supposed to remember long enough to affect his behavior!

Answer (score 2):

As the comment says, you're probably overthinking it:

- It's been a while since I read the books but I'm pretty sure that over the course of the series Farmer made some changes in the way souls behave, so I'd think the most likely explanation is that Farmer really wanted to introduce the idea that souls could become lost and it's just an oversight that Burton wasn't supposed to remember anything from the meeting.
- Maybe the Ethicals were able to and were planning to selectively erase his memory but somehow leave the idea in his head that he should stop using the Suicide Express.  That doesn't seem beyond their capability.

Comment: About the "oversight" idea: I'd've found that easier to believe if, say, a speech on Page 180 "contradicted" something stated way back on Page 10. But when the *same* character, in the *same* conversation, basically said "you *won't* remember any of this" and "you *must* remember to stop using the Suicide Express,"it *seemed* obvious to me, at the time, that PJF must have done it on purpose! (Also, I'd think a *good* editor would have noticed such contradictory statements within a few pages of each other -- and would only let them pass **if** PJF explained it was all part of a plan?)

Comment: On your second bullet point: By and large, I got the impression that the Ethicals were not in the habit of brainwashing people to "program in" mysterious imperatives to force them to do, or refrain from doing, certain things for mysterious reasons. I would be very surprised if their whole Council of Twelve had voted to "plant an anti-Suicide compulsion" inside Burton's skull . . . that would seem to violate the idea of giving everyone on the Riverworld a chance at ethical self-improvement by exercising their own free will as they were exposed to different cultures and philosophies.

Answer (score -1):

I think it was them putting on a show as you have previously stated- they were letting him know that glitches can happen & that just like he may not be resurrected- he can also remember things that should have been wiped from his mind.